# android: create function for sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, distance, trigonometry

i need to create a function for sqlite, because the sin and cos mysql-function doesn't exist, and i need to make a query like:

```
    String q = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE _id > 0 AND distance(lat, lng, latitudine, longitudine) < 20 AND cancellato=0 ORDER BY _id";
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(q, null);
    return c;
```

so, i need a function for distance.

and i can't do it via code because it's a list of +8000 shops!

how can i? i didn't found anything on the web.

thanks!

Comment: you could use square instead of circle ... or ... make some webservice for doing this ...

Comment: sqlite has some limitation so you can not get more function like another databse eg. oracle

Comment: in the iphone i made a function distance and i use it in sqlite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite

Answer (score -2):

distance(lat, lng, latitudine, longitudine)

I think you have to calculate distance pragmatically from your javacode then you can compare

```
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html
```

Comment: this is exactly what he wrote ... `because the sin and cos mysql-function doesn't exist` and he is asking what he can  use instead

Comment: right, and i can't make a query of 8000 record, and after this parse it. it's a query veeeery long