# Custom SQLite using Android NDK, SQLite source code

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm developing an app which use new google maps (see google play services and libs) and gps localization. In my app, I also have a SQLite db composed by a single table called **POI(DOUBLE Latitute,DOUBLE Longitude,VARCHAR(45) POIName)**. At **every** new gps value (LatLng) i need to query the db to get the nearest POI. To do that i need to use this [algorithm](http://www.spadamar.com/2007/12/calcolo-della-distanza-geodetica-tra-due-punti-della-superficie-terrestre/) and wrote something of similar in sql.
not difficult. right?

the real problem is: SQLite doesn't have cos, sin and acos functions. I tried to follow this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite) using SQLite source code, Android NDK, Cygwin (I'm using W8) and my project... all togethers, reading the official doc, but with no result.

is there some ***good*** tutorial about this? or can someone explain me **step-by-step** how to do that?

[EDIT: more info]
i created in my project a jni folder and i put inside: SQLite Source code; Android.mk.

Android.mk

```
#LOCAL_PATH is used to locate source files in the development tree.
#the macro my-dir provided by the build system, indicates the path of the current directory
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

#####################################################################
#            build sqlite3                                            #
#####################################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/sqlite-amalgamation-3070900
LOCAL_MODULE:=sqlite3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=sqlite3.c
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

in cygwin I move to android-ndk-r8e folder and run this:

```
./ndk-build -C 'C:/Eclipse/Workspace/MyApp'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile it at [No rule to make target error android ndk build sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811100/no-rule-to-make-target-error-android-ndk-build-sqlite/17846438). I'm stuck at actually trying to use the library though right now =/