# Splitting letters and number in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have one column containing letters and numbers (mix/random)

```
914103B01292AB21HRVH92665
```

i need to split it like this

```
914103012922192665 -numbers only
BABHRVH            -letters only
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in SQLite is with a series of REPLACE functions - like so:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(the_string, '0', ''),
                                                                               '1', ''),
                                                                       '2', ''),
                                                                '3', ''),
                                                       '4', ''),
                                               '5', ''),
                                       '6', ''),
                                '7', ''),
                         '8', ''),
                 '9', '') as letters_only,
  ...
```

- with a similar series of 26 `replace` function calls to strip out the letters, leaving the numbers only.

Alternatively, you could write a user-defined function to do this for you; this is a non-trivial exercise in SQLite - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099).