# Custom collation for SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, function, collation

I am creating a database in an Android application. Values in a text column are really unique if they meet the following requirements:

- No null strings. `NOT NULL`
- No equal strings. `UNIQUE`
- No empty strings. `CHECK`.
- Case considerations shouldn't be ignored. If "Lorem" is already in the column, "LoREM" shouldn't be inserted.

I read about [user-defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7867099/1065835) a little. Do I have to create one the last requirement to be met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `COLLATE NOCASE` to the column specification to get the fourth requirement met.

Comment: It works, but if I need to support symbols that aren't presented in the English alphabet, I'll have to write my own function as [they](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283265/1065835) say