# How to specify the sort order for the query to a content provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am trying to load all items from a Sqlite Table in Android and want to order the result.

How do I specify the order for the returned cursor?

I query the ContentProvider through a CursorLoader the following way:

```
new CursorLoader(context, RepresentativeEntityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686415/how-to-sort-the-cursorloader-results

Comment: additional to accepted answer: its possible to sort for more then one column, e.g. `"column_name1 ASC, column_name2 DESC, column_nameN ASC"` where DESC means descending.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try below code change COLUMN_NAME with actual column name on which you wants to sort.

```
new CursorLoader(context, RepresentativeEntityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, "COLUMN_NAME ASC");
```

Comment: for example if you're looking for images and you want to see the latest first - add: "date_modified DESC"

Answer (score 12):

```
new CursorLoader(context, RepresentativeEntityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, "column_name ASC");
```

or

```
new CursorLoader(context, RepresentativeEntityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, "column_name DESC")
```

;