# SQLiteException when executing rawQuery - syntax error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting a `SQLiteException` / a **SQL syntax error** when executing the following **rawQuery**:

**Code:**

```
public static final String NAME = "name";   
public static final String LONG = "longitude";   
public static final String LAT = "latitude";
public static final String IDENTNR = "identNr";
public static final String IDENTSTR = "ident";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "communities";

public Cursor findClosest(double lng, double lat) {

     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME + ", " + LAT + ", " + LONG + ", " + IDENTNR + ", " + IDENTSTR + " SQRT(" +
                "POW(69.1 * (latitude - " + lat + "), 2) + " +
                "POW(69.1 * (" + lng + " - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance " +
                "FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance DESC", null);

     return c;
}
```

**Logcat error message:**

```
03-20 15:46:07.248: E/AndroidRuntime(20605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 15:46:07.248: E/AndroidRuntime(20605): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 17): , while compiling: SELECT name, latitude, longitude, identNr, ident SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - 48.2347197), 2) + POW(69.1 * (16.3550203 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM communities HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance DESC
03-20 15:46:07.248: E/AndroidRuntime(20605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Unfortunately I am not very experienced with SQL statements and cannot figure out where my syntax error might be?

Do the functions `SQRT()`, `POW()` and `COS()` exist in SQL and am I using them correctly?

My table name is definitely correct and my database / table contains values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, correct this :

```
IDENTSTR + ", " + " SQRT(.....
```

Comment: That did it, thanks :) now I'm getting a NoSuchFunctionError which means I cannot use the functions I named in SQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know these functions do not exist in SQLite.  You can, however, add functionality.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite) StackOverflow post for more info.