# Creating custom function in sqlite3 in android

Tags: java, android, c, sqlite, android-ndk

I need to add a custom function in sqlite3 in android app to calculate distance between two geo coordinate. i have found a [c function](http://daveaddey.com/?p=7) which can be added as a custom function in sqlite3.

I am using NDK to compile sqlite3 files to create `.so` file. But I am not sure where to put code for my custom function which is also written in `C` and where to call `sqlite3_create_function(...)` which attaches custom function with sqlite so I can use my custom function in sqlite queries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, in general and for all purposes, you can´t!
but, there´s a workaround if you can install your own sqlite [How can I create a user-defined function in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-can-i-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite)

Comment: i just want to know where will put sqlite3_create_function() and how it will be call to setup communication with custom function.Is there any demo please provide.

Comment: ya i have implement all steps in app.but can not call custom function and through exception (does not found function)