# How can I create a user-defined function in SQLite in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite.net

I tried to execute this query in xamarin

```
SELECT * FROM GPSPoint WHERE SQRT( POW({0}-lat,2) + POW({1}-lng,2) ) < 5*5
```

But it gave me the error message

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: no such function: SQRT
```

And after searching I found that **Android** developers can use the [sqlite3_create_function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283265/4614264) method to create new functions in SQLite.

How can I do the same thing in xamarin?

Comment: AFAIK Just like with stored procedures, functions cannot be created in SQLite.

If you find I'm wrong please LMK as would be beneficial for me.

Comment: im not even sure thats a valid query either. SQL queries would be `WHERE col = value`

Comment: @Takarii It is a valid query in c# syntax. The original statement is `var query = conn.Query<GPSPoint>(string.Format("SELECT * FROM GPSPoint WHERE SQRT( POW({0}-lat,2) + POW({1}-lng,2) ) < 5*5", lat, lng));`

Comment: @jj- But android developers can create new functions. please refer to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283265/4614264).

Answer (score 0):

In the following example i make my custom sqlite function called
**MySqliteAdd** , which has two arguments as input and their sum as a result

```
[SqliteFunction(FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar, Arguments = 2, Name = "MySqliteAdd")]
public class MySqliteAdd : SqliteFunction
{
   public override object Invoke(object[] args){
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) + System.Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
   }
}
```

You can use it in a sqlite query like below

```
Select MySqliteAdd(25,35)
```

which will give you a result of 60

finally you have to register the function before you initialise your connection

```
SqliteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(MySqliteAdd));
```